# Multiple email addresses per user

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365, exchange

I am looking to set up a system where each user in my organisation can have multiple email addresses on various domains representing different brands. I want each user to have one "master" identity that would be used to let them log into additional external services, as much as possible via SSO. So a person called Certain User might have email addresses certain.user@domainx.com and certain.user@domainy.com. They would use the @domainx.com address as their main identity, but also have the @domainy.com support receiving AND sending emails with Outlook. Ideally, all the emails would go into the same mailbox, to avoid having each user managing multiple mailboxes. I would also need the ability to create some dummy email addresses not linked to real users and thus without SSO support.

The system would need to be Microsoft-based (AD, Exchange, Microsoft 365, Azure, some combination thereof), but I am not yet sure which exact solution would be best.

What setup would get me the closest to this goal?

Comment: This is really not a place for commercial solution recommendations... that being said, are there even actually mail systems out there that _don't_ support aliases?

Comment: Thank you for your time, @user1686. I think I'm missing something - are you saying this is not a forum for questions about MS Outlook or Office 365? Because these tags exist and have thousands of questions under them. So I'm not sure what am I missing here?

Comment: It's not even a forum to begin with; it's a technical support board. There's a bit of a difference between "how do I deal with this issue in that Outlook feature" and "recommend me a product".

Comment: Fair enough, I think I understand a little better. Thank you for the clarification. I think I projected a little bit my understanding of how GIS Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow work, where I think my type of question would be more acceptable. Should I delete it?

Answer (score -1):

Microsoft now supports sending as alias in Office 365, so you can try to use it.
See this: https://www.derekseaman.com/2021/04/microsoft-365-can-now-send-email-as-proxy-address.html

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Comment: This looks promising, thank you! I will take a closer look.